# Zip application from the current folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, archive

i’ve node.js app that I Need to zip all the current folder with command from 
and get the zip on the root

For that I want to use the [archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) npm package but I don’t understand the following:

> 1. where I put the current folder (since I want to zip all the application )
> 2. where should I put the name of the zip (the zip that should be created when execute the command)

My app have the following structure

```
MyApp
  Node_modules
  server.js
  app.js 
  package.json
  arc.js
```

In the `arc.js` I’ve put all the zip logic so I guess I need to provide zipPath (which in my case is ‘./‘) 
and zip name like myZip…

I tried with the following without success, any idea ?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');

// create a file to stream archive data to.
var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/.');
var archive = archiver('zip', {
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});

// listen for all archive data to be written
output.on('close', function() {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

archive.on('warning', function(err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        // log warning
    } else {
        // throw error
        throw err;
    }
});

// good practice to catch this error explicitly
archive.on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
});

// pipe archive data to the file
archive.pipe(output);
```

I need that when I open the command line like

`folder->myApp->` run zip arc and will create zipped file under the current path (which is the root in this case....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](https://archiverjs.com/docs/Archiver.html#glob) method, but make sure to exclude `*.zip` files. Otherwise the zip file itself will be part of the archive.
Here is an example:

```
// require modules
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');

// create a file to stream archive data to.
var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/example.zip');
var archive = archiver('zip', {
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});

// listen for all archive data to be written
output.on('close', function () {
    console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
    console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
});

// good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking errors)
archive.on('warning', function (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        // log warning
    } else {
        // throw error
        throw err;
    }
});

// good practice to catch this error explicitly
archive.on('error', function (err) {
    throw err;
});

// pipe archive data to the file
archive.pipe(output);

archive.glob('**/*', { ignore: ['*.zip'] });

archive.finalize();
```

Comment: I need some simple way to execute it... example will be very helpful ?maybe to add it to the script section in the package.json, not sure how since I need to node...

Comment: Just do `node arc.js` in your cmd, or in package.json add `"archive": "node arc.js"` to the script section.

Comment: Last question , when I run it with `node arc.js` it's working as expected... now I put in the `script` tag  (package.json) `"archive": "node arc.js"` and when I run it with `node archive` I got error, any idea how to run it from the script ? thanks!

Comment: To run a script from the package.json file you use npm. So just do `npm archive`. That's it. [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) is nodes package manager. ;)

Comment: In addition can you just shortly what does this do?  `archive.glob('**/*',`

Comment: Yes I've tried it `npm archive` but i got this : Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit,
    explore, get, help, help-search, i, init, install,
    install-test, it, link, list, ln, login, logout, ls,
....

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the root folder within your terminal when running `npm archive` ?

Comment: Yes im sure , this is strange ...I was able to run the `node arc.js` from the root which works ok...any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156050/discussion-between-daviddomain-and-nina-watcher).

Answer (score 0):

In the [github of node-archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) there is an [example folder](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/blob/master/examples/pack-zip.js)

---

---

> where I put the current folder (since I want to zip all the
>   application )

Example :

```
var file1 = __dirname + '/fixtures/file1.txt';
var file2 = __dirname + '/fixtures/file2.txt';

archive
  .append(fs.createReadStream(file1), { name: 'file1.txt' })
  .append(fs.createReadStream(file2), { name: 'file2.txt' })
  .finalize();
```

Specifically about your case and directory you can use the [.directory() method of archiver](https://archiverjs.com/docs/Archiver.html#directory)

---

> where should I put the name of the zip (the zip that should be created
>   when execute the command)

Example :

```
var output = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/example-output.zip');
```

Comment: Thanks , I saw this already but this is talking about specific file (file1&2) i want to do it for the entire application ...